# Working with QueryObjects and modules in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

Just starting working with Rails QueryObjects.
I would like to group them in modules and submodules, but it doesn't work.

With a simple QueryObject test, it works:

```
class CountriesQuery
  def initialize()
  end

  def call()
    Country.where("id=1")
  end
end
```

In Controller:

```
@countries = CountriesQuery.new.call()
```

Now, I tried this:

```
module Shared
  module Countries
    class CountriesQuery
      def initialize()
      end

      def call()
        Country.where("id=1")
      end

    end
  end
end
```

My folder structure is queries > shared > countries > countries_query.rb

Controller:

```
@countries = Shared::Countries::CountriesQuery.new.call()
```

And the error is:

```
undefined method `where' for Shared::Country:Module
```

But `Country` is a model, nothing to do with a module...

So, how to use namespace/modules AND QueryObjects together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have `country.rb` which implements the model of the same name.

If so, you want to reference the constant correctly:

```
::Country.where("id=1")
```

Comment: OK, it works. But I don't understand why Rails can't find the model without :: ?

Comment: `::` is a namespace resolution operator. When you want to reference some constant inside deeply nested module you usually have to reference it this way to avoid ambiguity and to help Rails know which exactly constant you need. By default, without `::` it will look for `Shared::Countries::CountriesQuery::Country`, then `Shared::Countries::Country` and then for `Shared::Country` and when it failed to find any of those you get exception.

Comment: @alex.bour you can read more about constants lookup in Ruby to get deeper understanding

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I understood. I have read many articles about QueryObjects or ServicesObjects but rarely with complex modules...